# Almost a week without new build

Tags: support, localization, revision-number

Just noticed that today is the end of April 28th UTC, but site revision number is still 2023.4.21.43403 (see the right bottom corner of the any SE page). I.e no builds were published since a week.

What is the reason for it? Are we waiting for some major update? Or what? I remember such long delay with builds only on Christmas, when WinterBash has been started.

I'm asking about this generally because without new build we can't deploy updated translations to localized sites like:

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/
- https://rus.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is there some fixed publication frequency for new builds that you are privy to? Some SLA about how often they publish releases? Do they owe you background information on their build pipelines and schedules? If you want to know about timelines for code deployments maybe you should join the dev team.

Comment: Historically, the company has its annual meeting/get-together in April.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum every one in the meeting, no one in development?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ I would expect that's kind of how an all-company meeting would work, yes.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 I'm pretty sure that this very depends on the company's size.

Comment: Right, so you think a company with 500+ employees would tell a handful of their developers to stay at their desk pushing builds to the web site? Do you think only developers are involved with pushing (and supporting, and monitoring) changes to the site? Why? Why does the size of a company change the meaning of an all-company meeting?

Comment: @Stuckat1337 could you please clarify what's "annual meeting/get-together" then?

Comment: Well, I don't work there, but it seems logical that a large annual meetup (like ones mentioned here in the past) would involve enough people that a code freeze makes sense. But companies can have code freezes or deployment delays for as long as they want and for whatever reason they want. Not sure anyone owes you a reason. :-)

Comment: Anyway to fix this, get hired to Stack Overflow the company, become VIP of development, and you can deploy update every hour. Simple. :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to close the loop on this, yes, the reason for the lack of builds was our company meetup. We were in a code freeze for non-emergent issues, which is lifted as of today.

Folks are back now, so we'll see things start to spool up pretty quickly.

Thank you all for your patience.