# Is there publicly available build history of the sites?

Tags: support, statistics, architecture, revision-number

I got a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388764/almost-a-week-without-new-build#comment1296297_388764) on my recent [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388764/339911) about the reason why there are no recent builds on SE sites:

> Historically, the company has its annual meeting/get-together in April.

I understood that comment in the following sense: "The number of builds are significantly less than usually due to the annual meeting week".

Based on that assumption I have a question:

Is there publicly available build history of the sites? I'm sure that detailed history is only available on git repo, so only employees can reach that (since the codebase is not open source). But what about generalized statistics like number of builds per day (without any additional details)?

Comment: wait. what does an annual meeting/get-together have to do with a site's build history? and why do you care?

Comment: @starball the reason is stated on linked question *"I'm asking about this generally because without new build we can't deploy updated translations to localized sites."* I'm also curious as you, I don't understand how annual meetings should relate to sites codebase build. But according to the comment that I cited here, it seems there's some dependency. So I'm asking is there a place where I can try to look at this.

Comment: oh. Is this not the kind of reason that we say that questions should be clear and understandable on their own right (without having to read through linked contexts)?

Comment: @starball please, don't hesitate to make an edit in my post. I always happy when someone improves my posts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @starball please look on updated version of the post. If it's still not clear please edit.

Comment: What would "number of builds per day" tell you? No two days are alike; one day it could take five tries to deploy a simple typo, and the next there could be massive, site-sweeping changes in a single commit. So I'm not sure how this metric would be even remotely useful except to the extremely nosy.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 as a starting point I'm interested is there same delay in builds at the end of April each year before or not.

Answer (score 6):

You can analyze the build numbers in the footer (currently `rev 2023.4.21.43403`) from the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/meta.stackexchange.com).

| Year | Build number on January 1st |
| --- | --- |
| 2023 | 2022.12.21.43127 |
| 2022 | 2021.12.22.41046 |
| 2021 | 2020.12.18.38240 |

The first three components are self-explanatory; the latter one is the [revision number](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html) (by the way, it's SVN, not Git), which simply increases by one every time you do a commit *or* generate a deployment package. The table above seems to indicate there are about 2k-3k commits and deploys in a year (it may be different for older periods). How many *deploys* there are (or at least a lower bound, but e.g. stackoverflow.com is indexed so often, it should be pretty accurate) would require a script to scrape the build numbers of all snapshots and extract the unique ones. That is left as an exercise to the reader ...

Comment: So the only publicly available way is to calculate a diff between snapshots in wayback machine? No per day/week basis?

Comment: This is the only way I can think of right now.